# Denormalizer on MongoDb Embedded Document in Symfony API Platform

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am attempting to run a denormalizer (data in) on an embedded MongoDB document with Symfony 4.4 using the  API Platform bundle. This works as expected for normalization (data out), but for the denormalization process, nothing is fired on the embedded data, just on the parent data.

If this is the way it works, then I may need to move the logic for denormalization into the parent. Or perhaps I am just doing something wrong. What I am attempting to accomplish is throw exceptions on inbound requests that contain fields that have been deprecated. The classes which parse the annotations and scan the attributes work as expected, it's just determining where to plug it in and I was hoping the denormalization process on embedded documents would work.

Here is my services.yaml:

```
'App\Serializer\InvestmentNormalizer':
    arguments: [ '@security.authorization_checker' ]
    tags:
        - { name: 'serializer.normalizer', priority: 64 }
'App\Serializer\InvestmentDenormalizer':
    tags:
        - { name: 'serializer.denormalizer', priority: 64 }
'App\Serializer\ProjectNormalizer':
    tags:
        - { name: 'serializer.normalizer', priority: 64 }
'App\Serializer\ProjectDenormalizer':
    tags:
        - { name: 'serializer.denormalizer', priority: 64 }
```

Then my denormalizer class which never gets executed:

```
class ProjectDenormalizer implements DenormalizerInterface
{
    private const ALREADY_CALLED = 'PROJECT_DENORMALIZER_ALREADY_CALLED';

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $context[self::ALREADY_CALLED] = true;

        return $this->removeDeprecatedFields($data);
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        if (isset($context[self::ALREADY_CALLED])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $type == get_class(new Project());
    }

    private function removeDeprecatedFields(array $normalizedData) : array
    {
        $apiPropertyReader = new AnnotationReader(Project::class, ApiProperty::class);
        $deprecatedProperties = $apiPropertyReader->readAllHavingAttribute('deprecationReason');

        $errors = [];

        foreach (array_keys($deprecatedProperties) as $deprecatedPropertyName) {

            if (!isset($normalizedData[$deprecatedPropertyName])) {
                continue;
            }

            $errors[] = $deprecatedPropertyName . ' has been deprecated';
        }

        if (!empty($errors)) {
            throw new DeprecatedFieldException(implode('. ', $errors));
        }

        return $normalizedData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the docs you would find that serializer component does not have any `serializer.denormalizer` service,
thus your classes are not detected by auto discovery. [Symfony Service Tags](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html)

You need to follow and implement Normalizer which implements both normalizer and denormalizer logic in single class and register it as normalizer [Normalizer  & Encoder usages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#serializer-normalizer)

Then name convention is confusing as it sounds but your normalizer takes care of denormalizing if it has `DenormalizerInterface` and norrmalizing if it has `NormalizerInfterface`, by tagging your serializing logic to appropriate method, they will be called accordingly.

API platform it self has examples on how both works : [decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data)
Here is how you decorate normalizer in api platform :

## api/config/services.yaml

```
services:
    'App\Serializer\ApiNormalizer':
        decorates: 'api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item'
        arguments: [ '@App\Serializer\ApiNormalizer.inner' ]
```

Or you can register this normalizer as per symfony way :

## config/services.yaml

```
services:
    get_set_method_normalizer:
        class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
        tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

**Implementation:**

```
namespace App\Serializer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DenormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

final class ApiNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface, SerializerAwareInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(NormalizerInterface $decorated)
    {
        if (!$decorated instanceof DenormalizerInterface) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The decorated normalizer must implement the %s.', DenormalizerInterface::class));
        }

        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsNormalization($data, $format);
    }

    public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        if (is_array($data)) {
            $data['date'] = date(\DateTime::RFC3339);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format = null)
    {
        return $this->decorated->supportsDenormalization($data, $type, $format);
    }

    public function denormalize($data, $class, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        return $this->decorated->denormalize($data, $class, $format, $context);
    }

    public function setSerializer(SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        if($this->decorated instanceof SerializerAwareInterface) {
            $this->decorated->setSerializer($serializer);
        }
    }
}
```

You can refractor your logic and create Normalizer Class for each entity. Regardless of what DB you use, for PHP and Symfony it's all objects.

Go through full docs here to understand how its implemented :[Serializer Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html)

Comment: The naming conventions that API Platform chose are VERY confusing and its odd that I cannot follow SOLID practices here by separating the processes out. I'll try this when I get back into the office. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, it is essentially data transformer class implementing normalize, denormalize interface. Service tagging will check if it is instance of either and call on respective method. You may try registering seprate class for denormalize it should work same, just use proper tagging so it gets captured by serializer.

Comment: So if trying in a separate class, just tag as a denormalizer as well?

Comment: I haven't got time to test it with api platform yet, in theory it should work, symfony expects instance of NormalizerInterface, DenormalizerInterface with proper implemented serializer, which would be api_platform.jsonld.normalizer.item for api platform.